# Webpage layout breaking on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css-float

The images below illustrate what the actual problem is
[image]

So as you can see this is a puzzle, and is being created by javascript. Each row is created like this.

```
document.write("<div style='float:none'>");
for(i=0; i < 4 ; i++) { 
        for(j=0; j < 4 ; j++) {
         imgArray[i] = "Images/" + x + ".jpg";
         document.write("<img id= " + x + " src='Images/" + x + ".jpg' width='120' height='120' style='position:relative;top:50px;left:50px' onclick='checkMove(parseInt(id))'/>");
         x = x + 1;
        }
        document.write("<br>");
}
document.write("</div>");
```

Even using `float` style keeps this problem. Is there a way to *lock* a window not to be resized smaller than `x`? Could you please point me in the right direction as in what im doing wrong, or not doing.

Comment: Thanks guys `width:N px` did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add a fixed width to your div?

```
<div style='float:none;width:480px;'>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give your div a width (in px), resizing will cause a scrollbar to appear.

```
document.write("<div style='float:none;width:600px'>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use css to set the width of the container div to the width of 4 images, which should be 480px.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the style of the div. That should prevent its contents from wrapping. Instead you'll get a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider min-width http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_minwidth.asp and the CSS equivalent.